# Separating business logic from data tempts me to use instanceof

Tags: polymorphism, business-logic

```java
class Foo {
    abstract doStuff() {}
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    doStuff() { ... }
}

class Baz extends Foo {
    doStuff() { ... }
}
```

From a functional perspective `doStuff` does exactly the same thing, however if it should be done to bar or baz then the implementation is completely different.

I try to separate data from business logic, so as `doStuff` is business logic and not class behavior, it should be outside.

```java
class Foo {...} // accessors inside
class Bar extends Foo {...} // accessors inside
class Baz extends Foo {...} // accessors inside

class Manager {
    doStuff(foo) {
        if(foo instanceof Bar) {
            return this.doBarStuff(foo);
        }
        if(foo instanceof Baz) {
            return this.doBazStuff(foo);
        }
        throw;
    }
    doBarStuff(bar) { ... }
    doBazStuff(baz) { ... }
}
```

Usage of `instanceof` has always been considered as a bad pattern for me and I always try to use polymorphism instead. However by separating business logic from data, I found myself stuck.

I could use a kind of accessor `getType()` and use a switch to avoid the usage of `instanceof`, but for me it is nearly the same issue as it seems to not use all polymorphism benefits. At the moment I have only 2 child classes and it should not be extended in the near future. So for now, I prefer to use `instanceof` instead of an accessor. People that read the child class will ask "What is it ?" about `getType()` because it is not related to data but it is a "flag" used by business logic switch.

By using a trait or composition to write business logic, business logic will be write in different files but just make it more difficult to read IMO.

What would you advise? Is there some other way I have not considered to fix it?

Comment: I depend on external services. Each one need to be call on a specific service.
It is related to our customer internal architecture/information system.
Even if I do not create a `doStuffWithFoo`, I will need to process a collection of Foo so in any case the switch will be done somewhere.

Comment: I know polymorphism can do it for me at run time, but only if I place my business logic inside my object. If I want to place it outside, then I do procedural programing and polymorphism do not apply. It is what I understood by reading about Anaemic vs Rich domain model thanks to @Philip Kendall reply.
I also understand having 2 functions doing the same thing but with different implementations seems to be irrelevant. Actually it is but it is not on my scope, I need to deal with it :/

Comment: Ok, I think I see your problem and may be able give you an example how to approach this.

Comment: Instanceof: Everyone knows what it means, and it’s impossible to get wrong. Gettype: Everyone has to look it up. Whatever arguments there are against instanceof, gettype is worse.

Comment: Where do you decide which of the instances (Bar, Baz) to create? If a conditional check should be anywhere, it should be confined *there*. What's the reason you didn't implement doStuff() directly in Bar and Baz? "doStuff is business logic and not class behavior" - what do you mean? High-level class behavior (which is different from implementation details of a function) *should* be an expression of the business logic, that's the whole point.

Comment: To me, this hinges on the details of the actual case -- in what ways are the operations in doStuff the same/different between Bar/Baz instances?  What is the Foo interface? etc.  IMHO, Just thinking about the problem in the abstract won't lead to a conclusion.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use both rich domain models

> I always try to use polymorphism

and anaemic domain models

> I try to separate data from business logic

at the same time. Both are valid programming patterns, but they take fundamentally different approaches as to whether the business logic code sits in the domain objects or not - you can't mix and match the two. Pick one or the other and stick to it.

Comment: In other words: use inheritance and embrace it with everything it has to offer (like polymorphism) or do not use it. It it pointless to apply it only to fight it.

Comment: It feels a bit like "He, who hunts two rabbits, loses both."

Answer (score 22):

Though [Philip Kendall's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/437521) has a point, I think it is oversimplifying. One can separate data from behaviour and still use object oriented means and polymorphism.

If you need your data (`Bar`, `Baz`) separated from your business logic, maybe for some technical reasons, you can keep `Bar` and `Baz`as pure DTOs and introduce separate classes for the business logic. Let's call them  `BarProcessor` and `BazProcessor` which both derive from some `FooProcessor` with a common entry point like `doStuff()`. Both classes can hold a data object the related type inside - passed by the constructor - and provide individual, polymorphic behaviour for each type.

Now, assumed you get a `Foo` object as input, you still face the problem to instantiate a `BarProcessor` for a `Bar` object, a `BazProcessor` for a `Baz` object, and so on. For this, you indeed may use a `switch` statement inside some `Factory` class. The point is that with a factory, you need the `switch` **only once** - the factory will encapsulate the mechanics in one central place, and it decouples it from the actual logic which may happen in your `Manager` class calling `FooProcessor.dostuff()`.

(Alternatively, I am pretty sure one could also utilize a DI container instead of a factory to instantiate the related `FooProcessor` for a given `Foo` object).

Comment: Would there by one (and only one) `FooProcessor` instance for each particular `Foo`, or would a processor by able to process multiple different `Foo`s?

Comment: @Bergi: both cases can make sense, depending on the specific use case and context (which the OP did not tell us).

Answer (score 4):

> Is there some other way I have not considered to fix it?

Double dispatch is one way to address this sort of problem.  This is a way to apply inversion of control to get your polymorphic objects to trigger behavior appropriate to their classes in other objects.  It is also known as the [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.  As applied to the problem posed, it might look like this:

```java
public interface FooVisitor {
    default void visit(Foo foo) { /* empty */ }
    default void visit(Bar bar) { /* empty */ }
    default void visit(Baz baz) { /* empty */ }
}

public class Foo {
    void accept(FooVisitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    void accept(FooVisitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

public class Baz extends Foo {
    void accept(FooVisitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

public class StuffDoer implements FooVisitor {

    public void visit(Bar bar) {
        // do Bar stuff ...
    }

    public void visit(Baz baz) {
        // do Baz stuff ...
    }
}

class Manager {
    public void doStuff(Foo foo) {
        StuffDoer doer = new StuffDoer();

        foo.accept(doer);
    }
}
```

Note that although they are lexically identical, the three `accept()` methods are semantically different because each one will be bound (at compile time) to a different overload of `FooVisitor.visit()`.  This is in fact the key to the pattern.

It may seem a bit wordy, but remember that you can define as many `FooVisitor` implementations as you like for tasks that need to distinguish among your polymorphic objects by their actual class.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Dave points out](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/437520/separating-business-logic-from-data-tempts-me-to-use-instanceof#comment960186_437520) in the comments, I believe your question is too abstract to be answered. I took the liberty turn it into a concrete (but still simplified) example.

```
class Pet {...} // accessors inside
class Cat extends Pet {...} // accessors inside
class Hamster extends Pet {...} // accessors inside

class PetFeeder {
    void feedPet(Pet pet) {
        if(pet instanceof Cat) {
            this.feedChicken(pet);
        }
        if(pet instanceof Hamster) {
            this.feedCarrots(pet);
        }
        throw;
    }
    void feedChicken(Pet) { ... }
    void feedCarrots(Pet) { ... }
}
```

So what is the problem with this code?
It is tightly coupled; whenever you want to add a new type of pet you also have to adjust PetFeeder, even for tiny changes like changing the name of `Cat` to `HouseCat`.
Instead, you want to have the model contain the differences that make you treat your `Bar` and `Baz` differently.

In our example this would be by adding a `isCarnivore` method to the `Pet` super class.

```
class Pet { abstract boolean isCarnivore(); }
class Cat extends Pet { boolean isCarnivore() { return true;} }
class Hamster extends Pet { boolean isCarnivor() { return false;} }

class PetFeeder {
    void feedPet(Pet pet) {
        if (pet.isCarnivore()) {
            this.feedChicken(pet);
        } else {
            this.feedCarrots(pet);
        }
    }
    void feedChicken(Pet) { ... }
    void feedCarrots(Pet) { ... }
}
```

If you would now add a new class `Bunny`, you can do it all in one place, let `isCarnivore` return true and be done with it.

In this design there is no automatic throw if a new class isn't known about. This is a feature and helps you to decouple business logic. But the drawback is that you wouldn't know if your new `Pet` is a carnivore, but only eats live mice.

If you need to be sure that your pets are not starving, you would want to keep the coupling of your previous design and look into the visitor pattern to get rid of the `instanceof`.

Comment: Why not just `pet.Feed(dinnerTable)` and it will figure out what to eat

Comment: @Tvde1 In my experience, that's not something you want to leave up to the pet. There's probably a programming-related lesson in that somewhere as well.

Comment: @Tvde1 From the title of the question, I assumed that it was the premise of the question that we want to separate the domain model (i.e. the Pet class) from the use cases (feeding). 
Obviously if that is not wanted, I agree your approach would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to separate data from business logic....

That's your problem right there: you appear to be taking this as a primary
*goal* rather than as a *technique* for making your code more clear and
easier to maintain.

Experienced developers treat things such as "separate data from business
logic" as guidelines, not as hard-and-fast rules. They are not applied
blindly, but applied because (and only when) they achieve better code.
Every time you apply guideline such as this, you should be able to say not
just, "I separated the business logic from the code," but "I separated the
business logic from the code in this situation because it made the code
better than the alternative in the following way: ...."

You need to look at your particular situation and imagine how it would look
and how maintainable it would be if you used technique *X.* If you're
finding it difficult to imagine, you might even try it both ways. That can
be done in the short term (sketch it out both ways and commit the one you
find better now) or even in the long term (use a certain design now, and
weeks or even months later try changing your approach if the current
approach is not working out). Since the result is dependent on the context
of the code, which changes over time, it may even be the case that when you
start one technique works better but as that area of code changes and
expands, or the code in other connected parts of the system changes, the
best technique to use there changes. (This is one of the reasons we
[refactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) code.)

Note that trying it both ways may even remain embedded in the production
code for some time. It's not unusual for me to have a chunk of code mostly
done in one way but where I've introduced a change in technique for a part
of it to see how it works out. This can take some time and require
examination by and opinions from other developers on the team; as we move
forward and better understand the implications and effects that technique
we'll either start refactoring other code towards that design or reverse
course and bring the new code back to the original design. (Many of my
attempts to improve code start with an incomplete move towards a different
design precisely so that I don't spend too much effort before being able to
evaluate the results, and so that if it turns out not to be going well I
don't need to spend too much effort reversing course.)

If you have any doubts about whether or not separating the business logic
is a good idea in your case, try it. There's no problem having
"experiments" in your code so long as everybody knows that those are
experiments and why they're being done. This should be explained in
comments in the code and also mentioned in the commit message. Writing out
a concise explanation of what problem you're wanting to solve, what you're
trying in order to solve it, and the benefits and problems the new design
introduces will not only help other developers understand what's going on,
but will help *you* better understand what's going on there.

This "try it out" technique does assume that you can fairly easily change
the code if what you're currently doing does not work out as well as you'd
hoped. That generally presupposes that you have support for this in the
form of being able easily to write and run tests and so on. If you don't
yet have that, you should probably focus some effort on doing that first,
especially since this can significantly affect the design of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use function overloading to only determine the subclass of `Foo` when you only have a `Foo` and don't know if it is a `Bar` or `Baz`, while allowing the caller to skip that step if they already know what it is.

```java
class Manager {
    doStuff(Foo foo) {
        if(foo instanceof Bar) {
            return this.doStuff((Bar)foo);
        } else if(foo instanceof Baz) {
            return this.doStuff((Baz)foo);
        }
        throw;
    }
    doStuff(Bar bar) { ... }
    doStuff(Baz baz) { ... }
}
```

This is a bit of a kludge and not elegant (not to mention almost identical to your original example), but if you must keep data separate from business logic it would work while still allowing the caller to skip the unnecessary steps if they can.

You're still trying to adhere to potentially conflicting principles, but this should do what you asked for when you already know if it is a `Bar` or `Baz`.

Comment: In a comment below the question, the OP wrote *"I will need to process a collection of Foo"*. So somewhere there will still be a function which gets only a `Foo`object and has to decide when to call `doStuff(Bar bar)` and when to call `doStuff(Baz baz)`, using instanceOf and a cast. Your suggestion would mean not to create a collection of `Foo` objects in the first place, only separate collections of Bar and Baz objects (and so making actually `Foo` and the whole inheritance superfluous).

Comment: ... there might be contexts where this works, but to me it looks the OP has a different case in mind.

Comment: Ah yep I didn't read all the comments. I will modify my answer.

Comment: I should also add this could have unintended consequences in languages like C++ where you can implement a class `Bat` that inherits from `Bar` and `Baz` but not remember that you need to update the `Manager` class.